# High CPU usage while uploading file to GCS with Java API

Tags: java, ssl, google-cloud-storage

Could anyone suggest what could be the reason that `com.sun.crypto.provider.GHASH#update(byte[], int, int)` takes lots of CPU while uploading a file to GCS in Java?

[Here](https://goo.gl/3ioWkl) is the code.

Looks like some internal SSL operation, however, SSL should not incur some much CPU burn.

[Complete stacktrace with timings](https://goo.gl/NTSVXY)

Env specs:

> java version "1.8.0_45"
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
> 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
>
> Ubuntu precise (12.04.3 LTS)

Tried google api versions:

> com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev26-1.19.1
>
> com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev33-1.20.0

Comment: Interesting. Which version of Java are you using? Googling around suggested that some versions of Java 8 had some odd performance regressions with that function.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Added some env specs. Ironically, Java 7 is no longer supported

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Any chance we can bypass this function to upload to GCS, in another api or with different upload configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, switching to `Java 1.7.0_80-b15` has solved the issue.
Even though sun's crypto methods, such as

`com.sun.crypto.provider.ARCFOURCipher.engineUpdate(byte[], int, int, byte[], int) ARCFOURCipher.java 12104 12104`

are still at the top of CPU consumers, they are much more moderate with this version.

[Link to related bug in JDK](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1135504)

Answer (score 2):

A similar issue happens on ***Amazon SDK***.

Upgrading *jdk8* to *u115* (it was older than *u60*) has increased our *AWS SDK* performance ***~4-5x*** .

So I'd like to emphasize that it's a general performance issue, not specific to GCP sdk (or AWS for that matter).

[image: 99 percentile]

[image: 75 percentile]